# jQuery / js toLowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, searchbar

I can't turn searchBox to a `.toLowerCase` and my code is case sensitive because of this. I want the code to scan on both upperCase and lowerCase letters.

I wasn't able to find a solution to my problem.

```
<script>
$("#searchBtn").keyup(function () {
    var searchBox = $("#searchBtn").val();

    var returnRows = [];

    $('tr').not('.headerRow').each(function () {
        var addRow = true;
        var $currentRow = $(this);

        $currentRow.find('td').each(function () {
            var $td = $(this);
            var word = $td.text();

            if (word.indexOf(searchBox) > -1) {
                addRow = false;
                return false;
                // console.log("KOMT IN IF STATEMENT");     //sla deze rij op in een tijdelijke array
            }
        });

        if (addRow) {
            returnRows.push($currentRow)
        }
    });

    if (true)
    {
        $('tr').show();
    }

    $.each(returnRows, function (i, v) {
         $(v).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you are making it a bit more complicated. Try something like this:

```js
$("#searchBtn").keyup(function() {
  var word = $("#searchBtn").val(), 
      timer;

  if(timer){ clearTimeout(timer); }

  timer = setTimeout(function(){
     $('tr').not('.headerRow').filter(function(){
        var txt = $(this).find('td').text();
        return txt.indexOf(word) !== -1 && txt === word;
     }).hide();
  },900);

});
```

`===` lets you compare strictly. So, in such case `T !== t` would result in `true`.